# I should get a variable declared in a class and use it into the same class but I don't receive error and it don't work

Tags: php, class, oop, variables

I Have this problem: I should get a variable declared in a class and use it into the same class but I don't receive error and it don't work. This is my code:

```
    <?php
class internal {
    protected $settings;
    private $ctoken = '';
    private $fparam = '';
    private $token = '';
    function __construct($ctoken, $fparam, $token){
        $this->ctoken = $ctoken;
        $this->fparam = $fparam;
        $this->token = $token;
    }
    public function settings($settings = ['disable_web_page_preview' => 'false', 'parse_mode' => 'HTML', 'MySQL' => true, 'PostgreSQL' => true])
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
        echo 'Settings caricate!';
    }
    public function botAdmin($user_id = null)
    {
        if($user_id == NULL){
            $user_id = $this->user_id;
        }
        if(in_array($user_id, $this->settings()['admins'])){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }


    public function SecTest()
    {
        if($this->ctoken != $this->fparam or $this->token == NULL){
            die("Security test: not passed, script killed.");
        }else{
            echo "Security test: OK. <br />";
            echo json_encode($this->settings);

        }
    }
    public function getSettings(){
        return $this->settings;
    }
}
```

I don't know what to do, I don't receive any error but if I call the method SecTest it print "null"

Comment: You never call the settings function to populate the settings property

Comment: Sorry, I don't wrote this on the post, but as I said below my $settings is declared with the call of settings() in another file.

Comment: Maybe in another file, but is in the same declaration of that object? Can you show how you're declaring and using the object? There isn't enough in your post here to see the full process.

Comment: Wait a moment please.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QX7buBSy

Comment: Your creation of `$internal` fails, since you don't pass in any arguments. https://3v4l.org/P18H8

Comment: Fixed that, but I have already the problem.

Comment: Try change to `$this->settings = $settings;` and try to avoid same naming to member and function...

Comment: Change `$settings = $settings;` to `$this->settings = $settings;` -- You assign the variable back to itself instead of to the class property.

Comment: Thanky you! But this isn't working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I was calling the method that echo the settings before declare the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Before your `_construct` method define the variables that are specific to your class.

```
class internal {
    private $ctoken = '';
    private $fparam = '';
    private $token = '';
    function __construct($ctoken, $fparam, $token){
        $this->ctoken = $ctoken;
        $this->fparam = $fparam;
        $this->token = $token;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dave! But, how can I fix my problem?

Comment: I thought my answer was clear but I guess not so I updated it to show you more clearly.

Comment: Yes, yes, I already do this, but my $settings declared with the call of settings() in another file return null

Comment: And did that other file create an instance of the class before calling the settings method?

Comment: Oh and you said you already did what my answer has but it isn't in your question.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.